# Some unclear statement in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So in my notes, it states that For **ANY** complex number $w$ in the closed ball $\overline{B(0,1)}$, there are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $f(w)e^{i\alpha}=|f(w)|$ and $g(w)e^{i\beta}=|g(w)|$ where $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on the unit closed disk.

Why is this true?

Comment: Since all of the numbers with modulus $1$ are of the form $e^{i \alpha}$, this equation ultimately says that $f(w)$ and $|f(w)|$ have the same modulus which is kind of obvious. That is when $f(w) \neq 0$; the statement is also formulated such that it is true when $f(w)=0$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(w)=0$, *any* $\alpha$ will work.

Otherwise, $\left|\frac{f(w)}{|f(w)|}\right|=1$ and therefore $\frac{f(w)}{|f(w)|}=e^{i\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you for the reply. But why does $|f(w)/|f(w)||$ in the first place?

Comment: Nevermind I just computed it using $x+iy$ and yes it works. Thank you!!